# I keep getting "GET" requests followed by "HEAD" requests. Is someone trying to be funny?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

They are literally back to back. I see a little message there but I'm young...

Is there a legit reason to send a back to back request using the GET and HEAD protocols on an Apache webserver?

There's been funny business before and we definitely need to be on guard.

Comment: Normally one issues a HEAD to check for expired document; only if expired, issues a GET to up to date version. At least that's how it was "back in the day".

Comment: Please add the log snippet that contains the get followed by head requests